# Same output amplifier

Tags: amplifier, power-amplifier

Is there a amplifier that will always put out the same value? The values are ac not dc

Example 1: 1 volt  signal in=> 5 volt signal out.

Example 2: 3 volt signal in=> 5 volt signal out.

Example 3: 5 volt signal in=> 5 volt signal out.

Example 4: 10 volt signal in=> 5 volt signal out.

In other words, no matter the input voltage the output will always be the same even if the voltage is higer or lower than the output.

EDIT

The amplifier is for a radio recivier where a decoder needs a certain voltage. I just used these values for simplicity.

Comment: Yes: make the input a dead-end and connect a 5 V voltage source to the output

Comment: Quick question, why would one need this? Just making sure this isn't a XYproblem case, more info at this [link](https://xyproblem.info/) If you just need a constant voltage source, no matter what the incoming voltage is, you could use a buck-boost regulator.

Comment: You are looking for "automatic gain control". You need to edit your question and explain that you want to amplify an AC signal which varies from X volts peak-to-peak to Y V p-p and output a signal with constant Z Vp-p. As originally written it looks like you are working with DC. The frequency is A to B kHz, etc.

Comment: Your requirements are insufficient without current, ripple V

Comment: I think you're not fully mentally clear about what an amplifier does. If something puts out a constant 5 V, it's not an amplifier, but a voltage source. Is it possible you mean "an amplifier that amplifies so much that the envelope of the output signal over some short time is constant"? The point here is that you need to look at a time-average of sorts, otherwise your requirement makes no sense.

Comment: a relay would do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re asking for is a circuit called *Automatic Gain Control*, or AGC. AGC measures the detected signal level and normalizes the gain to get a constant, useable output level.

AGC is widely used for radio receivers as well as audio (especially microphones).

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, amplify the signal which can overcome threshold voltage of a FET. Then, connect the output of the amp to gate of the FET.